# ember must call super method from component error

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-components, ember-controllers

i just extending my ember component with my custom mixins class but unfortunately my log said an error

```
    Assertion Failed: You must call `this._super(...arguments);` when overriding `init` on a framework object. Please update <cahyowhy-mini-blog@component:post-item::ember395> to call `this._super(...arguments);` from `init`.
Error
```

but in my component(post-item) i've been declared my init method

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import BaseController from '../controllers/base-controller';
import Likepost from '../models/likepost';

export default Ember.Component.extend(BaseController, {
  posts: "",
  applyLayout(){
    Ember.$(document).ready(function () {
      let $grid = Ember.$('#post-container').imagesLoaded(function () {
        $grid.masonry({
          itemSelector: '.post-item',
          percentPosition: true,
          columnWidth: '.post-item',
        });
      });
    });
  },
  init(){
    this._super(...arguments);
  },
..... more code
```

and this is my basecontroller class

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Mixin.create({
  init(){
    //this._super(...arguments); //nek ra dipanggil neng component post item ra keno :(
    let afterRenderExist = this.afterRender !== undefined && typeof this.afterRender === "function";
    if (this.applicationRoute.documentReady && afterRenderExist) {
      Ember.run.schedule('afterRender', this, function () {
        this.afterRender();
      });
    } else if (afterRenderExist) {
      this.applicationRoute.on('onDocumentReady', this, function () {
        this.afterRender();
      });
    }
  },
```

but when i try to uncomment this syntax `this._super(...arguments);` in my base controller. the error is gone...

can anyone solve this :( ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is you need to call `init` which is defined in `Ember.Component` if you don't then you will get an assertion error.

```
Ember.Component
   basecontroller (this._super is referring to Ember.Component)
      post-item (this._super is referring to basecontroller)
```

Simply to reach parent class which is `Ember.Component`. we need to `this._super` in all the places. Always calling `this._super(...arguments)` for init method is Good Practice.

Answer (score 1):

The function `init()` always exists and is defined in Ember (even if you didn't write it yourself). `init()` will do several things behind the scenes to make sure everything in your Ember application is working properly.

By extending your own version of `init()`, it's important that you preserve that key functionality that `init()` does before you write whatever you need to write.

That is why you're supposed to call `this._super(...arguments);`. Otherwise you would essentially be breaking Ember because you're overwriting some important functionality.

So basically, you actually need `this._super(...arguments);`, at the beginning of your `init()` function in order for everything to work properly. That is why commenting it out is giving you an error. If you uncomment it out then everything will be just fine.